# How to save selected check box in RCP application?

Tags: java, checkbox, swt, eclipse-rcp

I am beginner of RCP framework.I have used one Editor in eclipse RCP3 application name like "Food editor". In this one of Editor I have made one SWT table with **SWT.Check** Table item.
I have facing problem regarding check box selection.

Current scenario of this editor is, when Food editor open then I select check box then I open new Editor name like Employee_Editor. **Before Employee_Editor open, I closed Food editor with selected check box. Then again I open Food editor** then previous one "Selected" check box display  as "Unselected" why this happen?

[image: See this image for firstly open editor part.]

[image: I got problem regarding check box selected check box display as unselected.]

I tried to get solution of this problem I search on internet I found solution using database "selected check box" save as datatype boolean. 
But I do not want to do this because when many data comes many time SQL query fire.

So, I tried via defining one method "saveSelectedCheckBox" in createPartControl, which is save selected checkbox table item into "selectedTableItemList".
but in also I got problem when I close food editor then again I open it again I got problem with  "selectedTableItemList" with null value.
 I have share this code given below.

```
public class FoodDetailsEditor extends EditorPart {

public static final String ID = "rcp_demo.Editor.FoodDetailsEditor"; //$NON-NLS-1$Food_Details
public static final String BID = "Food_Details";
 private static final String STORE_SELECTION = "rcp_demo.Editor.FoodDetailsEditor";
private Table table;
 ArrayList<Integer>  selectedTableItemList= null;

@Override
public void createPartControl(Composite parent) {

    ScrolledComposite scrolledComposite_2 = new ScrolledComposite(parent, SWT.BORDER | SWT.H_SCROLL | SWT.V_SCROLL);
    scrolledComposite_2.setExpandHorizontal(true);
    scrolledComposite_2.setExpandVertical(true);

    Composite composite = new Composite(scrolledComposite_2, SWT.NONE);
    composite.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, false));

    table = new Table(composite, SWT.BORDER | SWT.FULL_SELECTION|SWT.CHECK);
    GridData gd_table = new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, true, true, 1, 1);
    gd_table.heightHint = 156;
    gd_table.widthHint = 565;
    table.setLayoutData(gd_table);
    table.setHeaderVisible(true);
    table.setLinesVisible(true);

    TableColumn tblclmnCheckbox = new TableColumn(table, SWT.NONE);
    tblclmnCheckbox.setWidth(100);
    tblclmnCheckbox.setText("Checkbox");

    TableColumn tblclmnTiming = new TableColumn(table, SWT.NONE);
    tblclmnTiming.setWidth(100);
    tblclmnTiming.setText("Timing");

    TableColumn tblclmnMonday = new TableColumn(table, SWT.NONE);
    tblclmnMonday.setWidth(100);
    tblclmnMonday.setText("Monday");

    TableColumn tblclmnTuesday = new TableColumn(table, SWT.NONE);
    tblclmnTuesday.setWidth(100);
    tblclmnTuesday.setText("Tuesday");

    TableColumn tblclmnWednesday = new TableColumn(table, SWT.NONE);
    tblclmnWednesday.setWidth(100);
    tblclmnWednesday.setText("Wednesday");

    TableColumn tblclmnThursday = new TableColumn(table, SWT.NONE);
    tblclmnThursday.setWidth(100);
    tblclmnThursday.setText("Thursday");

    TableColumn tblclmnFriday = new TableColumn(table, SWT.NONE);
    tblclmnFriday.setWidth(100);
    tblclmnFriday.setText("Friday");

    TableColumn tblclmnSaturday = new TableColumn(table, SWT.NONE);
    tblclmnSaturday.setWidth(100);
    tblclmnSaturday.setText("Saturday");
    scrolledComposite_2.setContent(composite);
    scrolledComposite_2.setMinSize(composite.computeSize(SWT.DEFAULT, SWT.DEFAULT));

    TableItem item1 = new TableItem(table, SWT.NONE);
    item1.setText(new String[]{"","10:00 to 10:30","Food1","Food2","Food3","Food4","Food5"});
    TableItem item2 = new TableItem(table, SWT.NONE);
    item2.setText(new String[]{"","11:00 to 11:30","Food1","Food2","Food3","Food4","Food5"});
    TableItem item3 = new TableItem(table, SWT.NONE);
    item3.setText(new String[]{"","12:00 to 12:30","Food1","Food2","Food3","Food4","Food5"});
    TableItem item4 = new TableItem(table, SWT.NONE);
    item4.setText(new String[]{"","13:00 to 13:30","Food1","Food2","Food3","Food4","Food5"});


    table.addSelectionListener(new SelectionAdapter()
    {               
        @Override
        public void widgetSelected(SelectionEvent event)
        {
            if( event.detail == SWT.CHECK ) 
                {
                  if( table.indexOf( ( TableItem )event.item ) == table.getSelectionIndex() ) 
                   {

                    TableItem ti = ( TableItem )event.item;
                    ti.setChecked( !ti.getChecked() );                      
                    System.out.println("event.index:-"+event.item);                     

                    }
                } 
              saveSelectedCheckBox(table);
        }

        private void saveSelectedCheckBox(Table table) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
             TableItem[] items =  table.getItems();
          selectedTableItemList=new ArrayList<Integer>();//Creating arraylist 

                for (int ro = 0; ro < table.getItemCount();ro++)
                {      if(items[ro].getChecked()== true)
                        {
                        System.out.println("items[ro]:=="+items[ro]);
                        selectedTableItemList.add(ro);
                        }

                    } 
                for(int row = 0; row < selectedTableItemList.size();row++)
                {
                     System.out.println("selectedTableItemList:--"+selectedTableItemList);
                }
        }
    });
}

@Override
public void setFocus() {
    // Set the focus
}

@Override
public void doSave(IProgressMonitor monitor) {
    // Do the Save operation    
}

@Override
public void doSaveAs() {
    // Do the Save As operation     
}

@Override
public void init(IEditorSite site, IEditorInput input)
        throws PartInitException {
    System.out.println("init called");
     System.out.println("selectedTableItemList:--"+selectedTableItemList);
    // Initialize the editor part
     if (!(input instanceof FoodDetailsEditorInput)) {
          throw new PartInitException("Invalid Input: Must be " + FoodDetailsEditorInput.class.getName());
      }
      setSite(site);
      setInput(input);
}

@Override
public boolean isDirty() 
{   
    return false;
}

@Override
public boolean isSaveAsAllowed() {
    System.out.println("isSaveAsAllowed called");
    return true;
}
}
```

I want when Food editor open then I select check box then I open new Editor name like Employee_Editor. **Then again I open Food editor "Selected" check box as display as a "Selected". How to do this possible? Please help me.**

My system configuration:

```
Windows 64Bit OS.
Eclipse Kepler 32 bit.
jdk 1.8
```

Comment: @greg-449:how to use doSave method and which file I want to save ?so how can easily load this value into editor part? please help.

Comment: @greg-449: actually I never used this method for saving file. So you can tell me which file most suitable to save this editor part?

Comment: @greg-449: I have modified doSave () method in Food Editor.         `public void doSave(IProgressMonitor monitor) {if (PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getActiveWorkbenchWindow() == null) {   return;
   } IEditorPart part = PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getActiveWorkbenchWindow().getActivePage().getActiveEditor();
  if (part != null) {
  IWorkbenchPage page = part.getSite().getPage();
  page.saveEditor(part, true);  }`                                                        **But Editor part does not save and thats why init() does not load save file. please help to saving editor part**.

Comment: @greg-449: Yes ,I am starting a food editor via handler,command class. I am using FoodDetailsEditorInput for editor input.what is code for init and input editor code?

Comment: @greg-449: I put code init(site,input) given below code: if (!(input instanceof FoodDetailsEditorInput)) {           throw new PartInitException("Invalid Input: Must be " + FoodDetailsEditorInput.class.getName());         
       }
       setSite(site);
       setInput(input); **but I cant able to load editor saved file.** please help me.

Comment: @greg-449:FoodDetailsEditorInput is input class for FoodDetailsEditor. in this input class implements IEditorInput class.

Comment: @greg-449: Does RCP provide a session?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you close an editor you lose it's state, and `createPartControl()` is performed again during open the editor. So you get your table in it's initial state. You should perform `TableItem.setChecked()` after you create your table and set values to the values of the previous user's choice. The best way to do it - turn the data in your table rows into objects and use [TableViewer](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseJFaceTable/article.html) to create the table.

```
private TableViewer viewer;
private List<WeeklyMenu> menu = Menu.MENU.getWeeklyMenu(); 

public void createPartControl(Composite parent) {
    Table table = createTable(parent);

    viewer.setInput(menu);

    for (TableItem item : table.getItems()) {
        WeeklyMenu weeklyMenu = (WeeklyMenu)item.getData();
        item.setChecked(weeklyMenu.isChecked());
    }

    viewer.refresh();

    table.addSelectionListener(new SelectionAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void widgetSelected(SelectionEvent e) {
            if( e.detail == SWT.CHECK ) 
            {
                TableItem item = (TableItem)e.item;
                WeeklyMenu weeklyMenu = (WeeklyMenu)item.getData();
                weeklyMenu.setChecked(item.getChecked());
            } 
        }
    });

}

private Table createTable(Composite parent) {
    viewer = new TableViewer(parent, SWT.BORDER | SWT.FULL_SELECTION | SWT.CHECK);
    Table table = viewer.getTable();
    table.setHeaderVisible(true);
    table.setLinesVisible(true);
    viewer.setContentProvider(new IStructuredContentProvider() {

        @Override
        public void inputChanged(Viewer viewer, Object oldInput, Object newInput) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void dispose() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public Object[] getElements(Object inputElement) {
            return menu.toArray();
        }
    });

    createColumns(table);
    return table;
}

private void createColumns(Table table) {
    TableLayout layout = new TableLayout();
    layout.addColumnData(new ColumnWeightData(10, true));
    layout.addColumnData(new ColumnWeightData(20, true));
    layout.addColumnData(new ColumnWeightData(20, true));
    layout.addColumnData(new ColumnWeightData(20, true));
    layout.addColumnData(new ColumnWeightData(20, true));
    layout.addColumnData(new ColumnWeightData(20, true));
    layout.addColumnData(new ColumnWeightData(20, true));
    layout.addColumnData(new ColumnWeightData(20, true));
    layout.addColumnData(new ColumnWeightData(20, true));
    table.setLayout(layout);

    TableViewerColumn column = createTableViewerColumn("Checkbox");
    column.setLabelProvider(new ColumnLabelProvider(){
        @Override
        public String getText(Object element) {
            return "";
        }
    });

    column = createTableViewerColumn("Timing");
    column.setLabelProvider(new ColumnLabelProvider(){
        @Override
        public String getText(Object element) {
            return ((WeeklyMenu)element).getTiming();
        }
    });

    column = createTableViewerColumn("Monday");
    column.setLabelProvider(new ColumnLabelProvider(){
        @Override
        public String getText(Object element) {
            return ((WeeklyMenu)element).getMonFood();
        }
    });

    column = createTableViewerColumn("Tuesday");
    column.setLabelProvider(new ColumnLabelProvider(){
        @Override
        public String getText(Object element) {
            return ((WeeklyMenu)element).getTueFood();
        }
    });

    column = createTableViewerColumn("Wednesday");
    column.setLabelProvider(new ColumnLabelProvider(){
        @Override
        public String getText(Object element) {
            return ((WeeklyMenu)element).getWedFood();
        }
    });

    column = createTableViewerColumn("Thursday");
    column.setLabelProvider(new ColumnLabelProvider(){
        @Override
        public String getText(Object element) {
            return ((WeeklyMenu)element).getThuFood();
        }
    });

    column = createTableViewerColumn("Friday");
    column.setLabelProvider(new ColumnLabelProvider(){
        @Override
        public String getText(Object element) {
            return ((WeeklyMenu)element).getFriFood();
        }
    });

    column = createTableViewerColumn("Saturday");
    column.setLabelProvider(new ColumnLabelProvider(){
        @Override
        public String getText(Object element) {
            return ((WeeklyMenu)element).getSatFood();
        }
    });

    column = createTableViewerColumn("Sunday");
    column.setLabelProvider(new ColumnLabelProvider(){
        @Override
        public String getText(Object element) {
            return ((WeeklyMenu)element).getSunFood();
        }
    });
}

private TableViewerColumn createTableViewerColumn(String name) {
    TableViewerColumn viewerColumn = new TableViewerColumn(viewer, SWT.CENTER);
    TableColumn column = viewerColumn.getColumn();
    column.setText(name);
    column.setMoveable(true);
    return viewerColumn;
}
```

Class `WeeklyMenu`:

```
public class WeeklyMenu {
private boolean isChecked;
private String timing;
private String monFood;
private String tueFood;
private String wedFood;
private String thuFood;
private String friFood;
private String satFood;
private String sunFood;

public WeeklyMenu(boolean isChecked, String timing, String monFood, String tueFood, String wedFood, String thuFood, String friFood,
        String sutFood, String sunFood) {
    super();
    this.isChecked = isChecked;
    this.timing = timing;
    this.monFood = monFood;
    this.tueFood = tueFood;
    this.wedFood = wedFood;
    this.thuFood = thuFood;
    this.friFood = friFood;
    this.satFood = sutFood;
    this.sunFood = sunFood;
}

public String getTiming() {
    return timing;
}

public void setTiming(String timing) {
    this.timing = timing;
}

public boolean isChecked() {
    return isChecked;
}
public void setChecked(boolean isChecked) {
    this.isChecked = isChecked;
}
public String getMonFood() {
    return monFood;
}
public void setMonFood(String monFood) {
    this.monFood = monFood;
}
public String getTueFood() {
    return tueFood;
}
public void setTueFood(String tueFood) {
    this.tueFood = tueFood;
}
public String getWedFood() {
    return wedFood;
}
public void setWedFood(String wedFood) {
    this.wedFood = wedFood;
}
public String getThuFood() {
    return thuFood;
}
public void setThuFood(String thuFood) {
    this.thuFood = thuFood;
}
public String getFriFood() {
    return friFood;
}
public void setFriFood(String friFood) {
    this.friFood = friFood;
}
public String getSatFood() {
    return satFood;
}
public void setSatFood(String sutFood) {
    this.satFood = sutFood;
}
public String getSunFood() {
    return sunFood;
}
public void setSunFood(String sunFood) {
    this.sunFood = sunFood;
}
```

}

And class `Menu`:

```
public class Menu {
public final static Menu MENU = new Menu();
private List<WeeklyMenu> weeklyMenu = new ArrayList<WeeklyMenu>();

private Menu(){
    weeklyMenu.add(new WeeklyMenu(false, "10:00 to 10:30", "Food1", "Food2", "Food3", "Food4", "Food5", "Food6", "Food7"));
    weeklyMenu.add(new WeeklyMenu(false, "10:30 to 11:00", "Food1", "Food2", "Food3", "Food4", "Food5", "Food6", "Food7"));
    weeklyMenu.add(new WeeklyMenu(false, "11:00 to 11:30", "Food1", "Food2", "Food3", "Food4", "Food5", "Food6", "Food7"));
    weeklyMenu.add(new WeeklyMenu(false, "11:30 to 12:00", "Food1", "Food2", "Food3", "Food4", "Food5", "Food6", "Food7"));
}

public List<WeeklyMenu> getWeeklyMenu() {
    return weeklyMenu;
}
```

}

Add this classes to your project and replace your `createPartControl()` with the cited code snippet.

Comment: @Ram You're welcome. Need to add, that the state of checkboxes depends on data (it can not be done in other way), and data will be initilized again every time when the app restart. So if you need to save state of checkboxes even after close-open the app, you should store the data somewhere (for example in file) and upload it when first accessed after launch the app.

Comment: @ Elena Larina: your work done perfectly,you are use jface table but is this possible in SWT table? if possible then how ?

Comment: @Ram Remove `if( table.indexOf( ( TableItem )event.item ) == table.getSelectionIndex() )` from your listener, add cycle on tableitems after creation of table. In cycle check, whether this number of item presents in `selectedTableItemList` and if yes, perform item.setChecked(true). But this is not OOP approach.

Comment: @ Elena Larina: after i removed if(......) condition i m confused, how to create cycle of table item fill, i have tried via init() method but does not work. can i shred init() code?

Comment: I want to create cycle of table item fill but where to put new code? pleasez help me.

Comment: @Ram After creation of `TableColumns`, before `addSelectionListener` in your code.

Answer (score 0):

```
    table.addSelectionListener(new SelectionAdapter()
    {  
        @Override
        public void widgetSelected(SelectionEvent event)
        {
            if( event.detail == SWT.CHECK ) 
                {
                   if( table.indexOf( ( TableItem )event.item ) == table.getSelectionIndex() ) 
                   {
                    TableItem ti = ( TableItem )event.item;
                    ti.setChecked( !ti.getChecked() );                      
                    }
                   saveSelectedCheckBox(table);
                }                
        }
        private void saveSelectedCheckBox(Table table)
        {
              for (int ro = 0; ro < table.getItemCount();ro++)//#32
                {      if(items[ro].getChecked()== true)//#32
                        {//#32
                        System.out.println("items[ro]:=="+items[ro]);//#32
                        selectedTableItemList.add(ro);//#32
                        }//#32

                    } //#32
                for(int row = 0; row < selectedTableItemList.size();row++)//#32
                {//#32


            //*For FileSaving try
            FileDialog dialog = new FileDialog(table.getShell(), SWT.SAVE);
             TableItem[] items =table.getItems();
             dialog.setText("Save");
                String absolutePath = dialog.open();
                if (absolutePath == null)
                    return;


                File fl = new File(dialog.getFilterPath() + File.separator + dialog.getFileName());
                FileWriter flwr;
                int cls = table.getColumnCount();
                        try {
                            flwr = new FileWriter(fl);
                            for (int i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
                                for (int j = 0; j <= cls; j++) {
                                    flwr.write(items[i].getText(j) + "\t");
                                }
                                flwr.write("\n");
                            }
                            flwr.flush();
                            flwr.close();
                        } catch (IOException e1) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            e1.printStackTrace();
                        }
        }
    });
```

Comment: @greg-449:I have more simplified code to save file , the when checkbox selected File-dialog open and save the file. but can you tell me how to load file and Then again I open Food editor "Selected" check box as display as a "Selected". How to do this possible? please help me